# Map Firestore saving field name

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, insert-update

can you help me? I have a problem to my code coz instead of updating my map value the path changes also

```
    const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    const availableRecord = firebase.firestore().collection('orders').doc(this.state.OrderId);
    availableRecord.update({
      stores: {  userId: 'On the way'}
  }).then(( res) => {
     console.log('Product is set into AVAILABLE')

    })
```

Instead of
  [image: this result]

the result is [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [square brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), as follows, should do the trick:

```
    const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    const availableRecord = firebase.firestore().collection('orders').doc(this.state.OrderId);

    const stores = {};
    stores[userId] = 'On the way';

    availableRecord.update({ stores }).then(() => {
       console.log('Product is set into AVAILABLE');
    });
```

---

Doing

```
  availableRecord
    .update({ stores: { [userId]: 'On the way' } })
```

also works, as you noted in your comment.

Comment: there are error sir. it says unexpected token so i changed it into  stores: {  [userId]: 'On the way'} and it works. thank you sir

Comment: Hello @janeviceral, yes there was an error in my answer, sorry ;-) See the update!

Comment: Thank you very much sir